# How can I parse JSON that has only a value but no name for it?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a JSON string in Java.

My JSON input looks like this:

```
{
  "id-1": {
            "att-a":5,
            "att-b":3
          },
  "id-2": {
            "att-a":5,
            "att-b":3
          }
}
```

I have tried to solve this with creating a parser that loops through every JSON Object he finds and stores those that match "id-" as a new Object and the following "att-" as the new Objects attributes.

Does any one of you know if there is a simpler way of doing so?

€: I want to store that information in an Object with a string variable called 'id' that contains the "id-.." string. The 'att-' variables are not the problem.

€2: I do not know how many "id-.." objects I get each time I query the server.

€3: Here my Java Object that I want to have created from the JSON:

```
public class Data {
    private String id;

    private String att_a;

    private String att_b;

    // Constructor

    //Setters and Getters

}
```

Comment: That isn't JSON. JSON doesn't use the `=` character in the object syntax.

Comment: you are right, sorry. couldn't copy it due to confidential information so i just wrote that down... :)

Comment: Where the attribute without name is?

Comment: Yup - this question is still very unclear. I suspect you could include a shorter piece of JSON, but include a much clearer description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: my problem is, that normally, I would write something like:
{
    "id":"id-1",
    "att-a":4"
}

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

Comment: That may be what you'd normally write, but it doesn't describe what problem you've got with the code that's been given here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do one of the following:

1. If you will always have the same number and the same name of "id-" values (eg 1 to 4) then create a POJO with 4 fields, id-1, id-2, id-3 and id-4. Each of these fields will be of type Id that contains fields "att-a" and "att-b". Then you just parse the JSON into your POJO using a library like jackson etc.
2. Get the root content as a JSON object (again, using jackson or similar library), and iterate through the children of the object (you can use getFirstChild and then nextSibling on each child) and add each entry to a list of whatever object you choose to use

**EDIT**

Looking through some old code, I have most recently used Google Gson for my parsing. In its simplest form:

```
String json = // insert your code here that gets your JSON as a string

JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement parsed = jp.parse(json);
```

Then one of these should work:

```
JsonObject obj = parsed.getAsJsonObject();
// OR
JsonPrimitive prim = parsed.getAsJsonPrimitive();
```

**EDIT 2**

I just threw this together - you'll probably want to tidy it up etc but should give you an idea:

```
public void test1() {
    String json = "{ \"id-1\": { \"att-a\":5, \"att-b\":3 }, \"id-2\": { \"att-a\":5, \"att-b\":3 } }";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode rootNode = null;
    try {
        rootNode = mapper.readValue(is, JsonNode.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    int i = 1;
    while(rootNode.get("id-" + i) != null) {
        JsonNode myNode = rootNode.get("id-" + i);
        // DO LOGIC WITH YOUR NODE HERE
        i++;
        System.out.println(myNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very good idea. Could you provide me an example of number 2, as I don't always have 4 members.

Comment: Added some short example code in the edit - I don't have any examples on me right now that can iterate through nodes, but hopefully that helps get you started

Comment: If you want to use Jackson (which I quite like) take a look at this page: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score -3):

not too sure about problem, and also as people mentioned there is problem with your JSON, but how about doing this ?

```
x: <<your stuff>>
```

just prefix that with attribute name?

Comment: The OP is *parsing* the JSON, not producing it.

Comment: add x: before trying to parse